# implementing a many-to-may association in Rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm working on a Video Tutorial application in Rails 4 (https://github.com/acandael/courseapp)

I'm thinking how best to implement the feature where a user can see which chapters he completed and wich videos he viewed. Completed chapters then get a 'Completed' tag beside them and watched videos get a checkmark icon beside them.

I think a way to implement this, for instance for chapters is to create a many-to-many association between the User model and Chapter model.

Two questions concerning this scenario. Does my join table needs an extra field besides the field for the user_id and chapter_id foreign keys, for instance a field 'is_complete' of type boolean ?

Second question, how can I check in my view whether a user has completed a chapter? Could I check this with

```
@user.chapter.is_complete?
```

Thanks for your advice,

Anthony

Comment: Yes. you need an extra field something like 'is_completed' in your join table. So you will have to use has_many through association here. I have a question, what do completed and viewed mean here?

Answer (score 0):

A many to many relationship is the best way to handle this situation.

```
class Chapter
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end


class User
  has_and_belongs_to_many chapters,
                          :as => :completed_chapters # Not sure about this

  def has_completed?(chapter)
    completed_chapters.include?(chapter)
  end
end

# Create a basic relationship here
user    = User.new
chapter = Chapter.new
user.chapters << chapter

user.has_completed?(chapter)
# => true
```

Comment: Hi screenmutt Thanks a lot for your answer. About the has_and_belongs_to_many method, isn't the has_many :through method preferred nowadays?

Comment: @Toontje it depends more on the requirement than the preference. The only difference here is for HABTM we don't have to create a join model but the join table still remains there (with only foreign keys from both the tables) while in HMT, we can add extra fields to the join table as in your case. And to handle these extra fields we have the join model.

Comment: Thanks Manoj. Now I'm thinking about it, a has_many :through relationship might be better then, as it might also be interesting to have a 'has_started' field in the join table.